# Why can't I get pdf file output from my web api on IIS server when I deploy it?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api

Web api has this method;

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetReport()
{
     var data = Logic.GetReportAsByteArray(...);

     HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
     response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(data);
     response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
     response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
     response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "filename.pdf";
     response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

     return response;
}
```

Web client consumes through this method;

```
...

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(...)

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

var data = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
return File(data, "application/pdf", "filename.pdf");

...
```

When I run on local I get pdf file as output via my web client. And via Swagger I can also get file output. But when I deploy on IIS server then I get blank pdf via my web client and via Swagger I get no file at all and response body has only the next one:

```
 {
  "Version": {
    "_Major": 1,
    "_Minor": 1,
    "_Build": -1,
    "_Revision": -1
  },
  "Content": {
    "Headers": [
      {
        "Key": "Content-Type",
        "Value": [
          "application/pdf"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Key": "Content-Disposition",
        "Value": [
          "attachment; filename=filename.pdf"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "ReasonPhrase": "OK",
  "Headers": [],
  "RequestMessage": null,
  "IsSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

Comment: try to write a trace on your server when you read the byte array, seems that the pdf file not exist or the array answered by Logic.GetReportAsByteArray(...); is emplty.

Comment: @Legion No. I checked there. I get the correct data

Comment: You might need to add a mime type entry in your web.config - https://blogs.iis.net/bills/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config (for you '.pdf' and 'application/pdf' )

Comment: What version of asp.net are you using. If core then you need to change the return type being used.

Comment: @HockeyJ These settings are already on IIS server

Comment: @Nkosi Web client is .Net core and Web api is .Net Framework (4.7.1)

Comment: @Y.Y. are you using `ApiController `or `Controller`

Comment: @Nkosi ApiController

Comment: If I have deployed on IIS 7.5 then it will work. But if I have deployed on IIS version 10.0 then I get a different response. It does not work. I have not yet been able to find the reason.

Comment: @Y.Y. I'm having now exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?